# Почему не проходит авторизация с помощью phantomjs?

Tags: phantomjs, веб-скрейпинг

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь пройти авторизацию с помощью phantomjs, но не проходит, вот код:

```
// Authentication 

"use strict";

var siteUrl = 'http://www.3dcontentcentral.com/secure/download-model.aspx?    catalogid=10260&id=496588';
var page = require('webpage').create();


page.open(siteUrl, function (status) {
if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('Unable to access network');
} else {
     console.log("Status: " + status);
     page.render('yes.png');
     var fs = require('fs');
     fs.write('page.html', page.content, 'w');
      //заполняем
    page.evaluate(function() {
    document.getElementById("3dcclogin").value = "mymail@mail.ru";
    document.getElementById("3dccpassword").value = "mypass";
    document.getElementById("btn_ucLogin").click();     
});

}
  page.render('yes2.png');
  fs.write('page1.html', page.content, 'w');
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Пароль и логин я изменил. Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так делаю?

Comment: в чем конкретно ошибка, что именно у вас "не проходит"?

Comment: я проверяю png-файл после авторизации, но в нем только заполненная попап-форма, по идее должно имя отобразиться на странице. То же самое и в html-файле, там тоже в правом верхнем углу кнопка login, вместо нее должно быть имя авторизовавшегося

Comment: @ZaurK Я думаю, вам нужно для начала так или иначе сделать паузу на секунду-две перед вторым рендером, иначе на экране просто не успевает ничего измениться.

Comment: Да, так и оказалось, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
///////всё работает без лишних слов//////////
var page = require ('webpage').create();
var system = require("system"); 


page.open("адрес сайта",   function(status){
console.log('открыто'); 
page.settings.resourceTimeout = 1000;   

    page.onLoadFinished =  function(status) {

          setTimeout(function() {

                page.render("ollgod.png");
                console.log('see ollgod.png');  
                phantom.exit();
            }, 10000)


        };



    page.includeJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js', function(){

        page.evaluate(function (){

            $("#ид или .класс").val("логин");
            $("#ид или .класс").val("пароль");
            $("#ид или .класс").click();


        });

            console.log('login good');
            page.render("before_submit.png");           
            console.log('see login.png ');              


    });

});
```